# Optimization Questions where a Max/Min doesn't occur

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am creating an Extra Credit assignment for my students and I want to show the important of checking that the critical point is indeed either a max or min.

1. Can someone point me to an OPTIMIZATION question where the Second Derivative Test fail?
2. Moreover, an OPTIMIZATION question where both Second and First Derivative Tests fail?

Comment: Add 1) $f(x)=x^3$. For 2. $g(x)=|x|$, since it is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: @callculus I should have mentioned, that it needs to be an optimization question